# Trying to upgrade C++ 6 project with a VB6 ActiveX exe

Tags: c++, vb6, activex-exe

I've inherited a C++ 6 project, and I am trying to upgrade it to C++ 2010
I haven't worked with C++ in years, and have found 2010 to be much more strict than C++ 6

The project has a reference to a VB6 ActiveX exe
There are 2 things in the ActiveX exe that are causing me problems
I've simplified the code, and made sure this still causes the same problem

```
Public SoapClient As New MSSOAPLib.SoapClient

Public Function GetDiscontinuedWithRelationships_RS() As ADODB.Recordset
    Set GetDiscontinuedWithRelationships_RS = New ADODB.Recordset
End Function
```

The C++ code defines these this way:

```
typedef void *PTR;
typedef PTR ISOAPClientPtr;
typedef PTR _RecordsetPtr;
```

When I try to build, I get an error in the tli file generated by the compiler for both SOAPClientPtr and _RecordsetPtr

error C2564: a function-style conversion to a built-in type can only take one argument

Any help, or Ideas of what I might try would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,

Brian